# Why do i get 0 instead of negative number when subtracting?

Tags: c++, string

I was trying to solve "codewars" kata. And it looked pretty easy at first. When I wrote the program, it was working correctly only with a positive return value. So, when the result is a positive number, it's OK, however, when trying to subtract, I always get 0 instead of a negative number. I thought that the problem could be with type of the `int`. So I tried to change it to `signed int`. But it didn't help.

So, the task sounds like this: you have to make addition and subtracting on a given string. The return value must also be a string.

Examples:

"1plus2plus3plus4"  --> "10"

"1plus2plus3minus4" -->  "2"

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>

std::string calculate(std::string str)
{
    std::string temp; signed int result = 0;

    for (auto& x : str)
    {
        if (std::isdigit(x) && result == 0 )
                               result = std::stoi(std::string(1,x));

        if (std::isdigit(x) && result !=0 )
        {
            if (temp == "plus")   // if it's operation PLUS than add
            {
                result += std::stoi(std::string(1,x)); // c++always get 0 instead of signed int
            }
            else          // if operation MINUS than subtract
            {
                result -= std::stoi(std::string(1,x));   // here always get result as 0
            }
            temp = "";
        }
        if (std::isalpha(x)) temp += x;
    }
    return std::to_string(result-1);
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't stack variable declarations. Do one per line.

Comment: I'd debug what `temp` is each iteration.

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code, statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Did you try to check, for example, that `std::stoi(std::string(1,x))` does what you expect it to?

Comment: `std::stoi(std::string(1,x))` can be simplified to `int(x - '0')` since `isdigit(x)` already verified that `x` is in the range of `'0'..'9'`

Comment: To help with debugging I also suggest you split complex expressions into smaller and simple expressions, so you can see their immediate results. For example, `std::stoi(std::string(1,x))` could be done as `std::string t1(1, x); int t2 = std::stoi(t1);`

Comment: @kirillshvedov [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/b6AQGO) using the *exact* code you have shown. What does your input actually look like that is failing for you? In any case, your loop should not be checking for `result == 0`/`result != 0` at all, because what if the running `result` was actually 0 halfway through the iteration, ie `"1plus1minus1..."`? Consider re-writing your check

Comment: @RemyLebeau i return std::to_string(result-1). So when the result should be negative like if the input was : "1minus2minus3minus4". It should result in "-8". But i get  always "0". But actually "-1" because of return std::to_string(result-1);

Comment: @kirillshvedov if you step through your code with a debugger, you would see that the very 1st loop iteration is wrong, for the reason I stated earlier. `x` is `'1'`, so `if (std::isdigit(x) && result == 0 )` is true, so it sets `result` to `1`, then the following `if (std::isdigit(x) && result !=0 )` is now true but `temp` has not been set to anything yet, so the code tries to subtract `1` when it should not, so `result` becomes `0` instead of staying at `1`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau about loop check( result == 0 / result != ). I was looking for a better solution for checking if result is already used or not. But the only thought i've come to is to use nullptr, but it's impossible with type signed int(not nullptr_t)...

Comment: @kirillshvedov use a separate `bool` variable to track the state of `result`. Or, change `result` to a `std::optional<int>`. Or, simply initialize `result` to the value of the 1st character before entering the loop, and skip the 1st character inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop should not be checking for `result == 0`/`result != 0` to know if `result` has a value. Think of what happens if the running result is actually `0` halfway through the iteration, ie `"1plus1minus..."`.

If you step through your code with a debugger, you would see that on the *very 1st iteration*, `x` is `'1'`, so `if (std::isdigit(x) && result == 0 )` is true, so `result` gets set to `1`, but then the following `if (std::isdigit(x) && result !=0 )` is now true.  But `temp` has not been set to anything yet, so `if (temp == "plus")` is false, and the loop falls into the code that subtracts from `result`, thus making it `0`, when it should not be changing `result` at all.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string calculate(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string temp;
    int result = 0;

    if (!str.empty() && std::isdigit(str[0]))
    {
        result = str[0] - '0';

        for (size_t i = 1; i < str.size(); ++i)
        {
            char x = str[i];

            if (std::isdigit(x))
            {
                int num = (x - '0');
 
                if (temp == "plus")
                {
                    result += num;
                }
                else if (temp == "minus")
                {
                    result -= num;
                }
                temp = "";
            }
            else if (std::isalpha(x))
                temp += x;
        }
    }

    return std::to_string(result);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/bguftR)